# If a listener is attached to a parent element, is it possible to distinguish which child element a click occured on?

Tags: javascript

If I have an onClick listener attached to an li element, then if that li has several child elements of different types then within the listener I could tell which type of element the click occured by examining the event.target.tagName or event.target.nodeName.

But what if there are two children with the same tagName, two images for example? Is it possible to identify which one the event is associated with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.target` is the same object you can get with `document.getElementById`. So, you can do all the same things with it. Take an id, name, class or any other attribute which may help you to find out which element is clicked.